# Safari 7 User Agent is set to “Custom” by default

Tags: macos, safari

Ever since upgrading to Mavericks from Snow Leopard, Safari’s default User Agent is set to custom. Anybody has any idea why this happens? And how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Do you have activated the developer menu? Do you see a menu "Develop" in your menu bar if safari is active? If so, what did you have chosen as User Agent in that menu?

Comment: Yes, I do, and the default User Agent is “Custom”. Every time I start Safari, it chooses “Custom”.

Comment: Did I understand that correctly: If you chose Default now, then restart Safari, the User Agent resets to "Custom"? That is not intended, normally it should always reset to "Default"(That's why it's called default")

Comment: @napcae, you understood correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix it by deleting the `CustomUserAgent` string in the plist file.

```
defaults delete com.apple.Safari CustomUserAgent
```

But I still don’t understand how it got to be like that in the first place.

Comment: This bothered me for the longest time. It could be that I once changed as instructed by coursera. Not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

This happens after you use `defaults write com.apple.Safari CustomUserAgent "\"My user agent string\""` command. Either your or someone who used your computer wanted to add a permanent user agent string to the browser. It not only adds the string permanently but also setting it to the default string. You can add a new string to overwrite it as well.