# Apps take forever to start on OS X Mavericks

Tags: applications, upgrade, macos

Ever since I upgraded my main machine to Mavericks, every time I open a new app, two things happen:

1. the app takes a long time to open;
2. the whole system slows to a crawl until the app opens completely.

The interesting part is that this happens on an early 2011 MacBook Pro (with 4GB of RAM), while on an older machine (mid/late 2007 MBP with 2GB of RAM), also updated to Mavericks, everything is a breeze—it’s surreal! (Both machines were upgraded from Snow Leopard.)

And on top of that, Safari is completely broken—see [my previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/107397/387).

What I’ve done so far:

- repaired permissions;
- cleared system and user cache;
- reseted the SMC;
- ran AppleJack;

What can I possibly do to make it work as it should?

Comment: Does this happen with every application, or just a select few?

Comment: Have you checked the disk for errors ? My 2012 MBP is faster than Mountain Lion with Mavericks.

Comment: @JW8 As far as I can tell, with every application. And also, it happens _every_ time I open them, not just the first time after a fresh restart.

Comment: @PratikaRana It was part of AppleJack set of utilities, so yes.

Comment: There are 2 great tools to start with debugging. One is the Activity Monitor to see who, what, the second one is the Console log.

Answer (score 1):

When I see things like this I often suspect disk problems. (This is a HDD, correct?) The first symptoms of soft disk errors are often bad performance.

Open the Console and see if you see any disk errors. Also try booting into a Super Duper clone. Since a clone will have the same files, any problem would continue if it were a configuration problem. But if the problem goes away, it was likely a problem with the physical drive. As a bonus, a clone is exactly what you will need if you have a physical drive problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you reinstall the application. If all goes wrong, then just reinstall Mavericks. My MBP (mid 2012) takes FOREVER to start up but the apps work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *clean install* of Mavericks (make sure you back up your data first) from a [bootable USB install drive](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/how-to-make-your-own-bootable-os-x-10-9-mavericks-usb-install-drive/).

There is also [step by step guide](http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/26/clean-install-os-x-mavericks/) available.

Comment: That’s one thing I’m trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I did a clean install. The first day it was o.k., but then opening apps takes a long time, watching the bouncing app-icons in the dock.

1. Mavericks fresh install (external HDs kept disconnected, two displays attached)
2. iWork (from CD)
3. Adobe CS4
4. iCloud activated
5. Canon printer driver

After i gave up when recurring the old behavior i installed back much other stuff, it can´t hurt anymore. Watching the ever bouncing app-icons in the dock, again. Crap.

Answer (score -1):

Buy a solid state drive.  Yeah, I know, expensive but EXCELLENT.  If you want an external usb 3 make sure the case has UASP. Very important.